# Python: Contour in binary 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, contour

I would like to in a simplest possible way (without million checking of boundaries of image) get the contour, with the width of n pixels going into the positive area, from the binary 2D array.

Example:

```
img = np.array([
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
               [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
               ])
```

For calling with e.g. width = 1. Pixels are positive if img[i,j]==1 and any neighbour (img[i+1,j], img[i-1,j], img[i,j-1], img[i,j+1]) is 0.

```
contour1 = get_countor(img, width = 1)
contour1 = ([
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
               [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            ])
```

or calling with e.g. width = 2. All pixels from width = 1 are positive as well as the ones that satisfy img[i, j] == 1 and for which with 2 indices away (euclidian distance) exists a pixel with value 0.

```
contour2 = get_countor(img, width = 2)
contour2 = ([
               [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
               [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            ])
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

for i in np.arange(10):
    df.loc[len(df)] = np.random.randint(0,2,10)

df = df.astype(bool)

contour = df & ((df-df.shift(-1, axis=0).fillna(1))|(df-df.shift(1,axis=0).fillna(1))|(df-df.shift(-1,axis=1).fillna(1))|(df-df.shift(1,axis=1).fillna(1)))
```

---

outputs:

df:

[image]

contour:

[image]

hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact answer for this question, but sharing a simple way to draw contours in images; for folks that are just looking for that.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter
import numpy as np


def draw_contour(img, mask, contour_width, contour_color):
    """Draw contour on a pillow image from a numpy 2D mask."""
    contour = Image.fromarray(mask)
    contour = contour.resize(img.size)
    contour = contour.filter(ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES)
    contour = np.array(contour)

    # make sure borders are not drawn
    contour[[0, -1], :] = 0
    contour[:, [0, -1]] = 0

    # use a gaussian to define the contour width
    radius = contour_width / 10
    contour = Image.fromarray(contour)
    contour = contour.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=radius))
    contour = np.array(contour) > 0
    contour = np.dstack((contour, contour, contour))

    # color the contour
    ret = np.array(img) * np.invert(contour)
    if contour_color != 'black':
        color = Image.new(img.mode, img.size, contour_color)
        ret += np.array(color) * contour

    return Image.fromarray(ret)
```

Check this test output: [image]

I wrote this solution whilst working for this [PR](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/pull/348).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is
[`scipy.misc.imfilter(img, "find_edges")`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imfilter.html).

Given a binary array `img` this will produce an array with `0` and `255`, so you'll need to divide by 255. As I see it, the filter with width=2 is obtained by applying the filter with width=1 another time, so at the end your function could look like

```
def get_countor(img, width = 1):
    for i in range(width):
        img = scipy.misc.imfilter(img, "find_edges")/255
    return img
```